# ISO Automatic French Press (grind fresh coffee, boil water)

Tags: coffee-machines, french-press

My husband loves French Press coffee but mornings often get too busy to boil water, grind coffee, etc.  I'd love to buy him an automatic machine but can't seem to find one that does French Press.  I found the Bodum Bistro Electric French Press, but it doesn't appear to be manufactured anymore.  Any suggestions?  If this doesn't exist, what's the closest taste?  Bonus if the machine offers dual hoppers (I prefer decaf).

Comment: Have you considered doing some prep work the evening before? Like pre-grinding the beans and filling the kettle?